# Dropbox API - PDF preview instead of download

Tags: pdf, download, dropbox-api, preview

I do requesto to `https://api.dropbox.com/1/media/dropbox/{FILE_ID}` to retrieve preview URL of a PDF file, then I do GET request on the URL, returned by previous API call, and I receive `content-disposition:attachment; filename="{FILE_NAME}"` header in the response which forces browser to download a PDF instead of previewing it.

The flow was working fine some time ago and I have been using `?dl=1` to force a download. Did the Dropbox API changed somehow? How do I force preview instead of download?

Comment: You can find some information about this here: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=115827#post-616577

Comment: This 'hack' worked like a charm! I wonder why there is no info about this in API docs. BTW @Greg you can post an answer so I can mark it as correct.